# how to make img-list stay on one line in desktop but drop down on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am having some trouble making a responsive list of images. My objectives is:

1. On desktop resolutions `1000px` and greater:

   - I need one line of images that never wraps and images always fit. I
     can accomplish that with this:

**HTML**

```
  <div id="partners" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#partners {
  background-color: #eee;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px #F00;
}

.logo-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width:1000px) {
#partners {

}

.logo-image {

}
}
```

2. On smaller screens:

   - the blocks drop down (responsive)

But as users access this page on mobile devices those blocks get smaller. So I tried to make the image retain normal size then drop down by removing the partners css when the screen `width` is anything less than `1000px` but that doesnt seem to work.

```css
  @media (max-width:1000px) {
    #partners {

    }

    .logo-image {

    }
    }
```

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/rx8d4xh0/1/)

I've been trying all week so far and at wits end, at this point I'm not sure it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the `display: block;` to remove the inline display.

Check the updated code here:

```css
#partners {
  background-color: #eee;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px #F00;
}

.logo-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width:1000px) {
#partners {
 
}

.logo-image {
float:left;
}
}
```

```html
  <div id="partners" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this works well, but im just trying to have it be full bootstrap responsive after width is less than 1000px. For example; if width is 970px it can at least fit 3 in a row and drop down the rest.

Comment: give it a width and use display: inline-block" instead of block :) try and update me if it works

Comment: naw it just puts it all together inline and doesn't become responsive when smaller: https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/rx8d4xh0/2/

Answer (score 1):

here is a simplified version of your Fiddle, just using `float:left/none`

```css
#partners {
  background-color: #eee;
}
img {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px red !important;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  img {
    float: none;
    display:block;
    margin:auto
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="partners" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that it drops down when width is greater than 1000px. Were as i needed it to maintain one line and images to fill that one line for desktop resolutions.

Comment: Ok, then you can change the classes from `col-md-6` to `col-md-12`, if you are using a framework, don't hack it, use the properties it have :)

Comment: ah! thank you, i got what i needed from the post i marked as the answer. But i would've rather used Bootstrap fully to do what i needed to do. I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: you always can change the answer accepted to the  one you think is more useful and helpful to you, it is really up to you :) If I were you I would stick to Bootstrap only, only in critical situations would use hacks.